# Ajax Auto Suggest v.2 suggestion depends on radio button?

Tags: autocomplete

I am using auto suggest v.2.1.3 from brandspankingnew.
I have a form with two radio button and a text field and would like to know how to make the auto suggest script pointing to a different php file if one of the radio button is checked.
I tried this but it doesnt work, its always point to the same php file even if second button is checked
Could you please assist?

Many thanks in advance.

My code is as follows:

function targetvalue() 
    {
        for (i=0;i

/>Business  Street

var options = {
        script:"autosuggest.php?json=true&limit=6&",
        varname:"input",
        json:true,
        shownoresults:false,
        maxresults:10,
        callback: function (obj) { document.getElementById('name').value = obj.id; }
    };
    var as_json = new bsn.AutoSuggest('business', options);


    var options_xml = {
        script: function (input) { return "autosuggest.php?input="+input+"&testid="+document.getElementById('testid').value; },
        varname:"input"
    };
    var as_xml = new bsn.AutoSuggest('business', options_xml);

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the easiest solution is to pass the the button state to the one script eg only one script but can return different results depending on button state. Otherwise you need to rewrite options each time someone clicks on the radio button. The second solution an lead to unpredictable behavior of auto suggest component.

---

Sample script:

```
var selectedValue = getRadioSelectedValue("radioGroupName");
var options_xml = { script: function (input) { return "autosuggest.php?input="+input+"&testid="+document.getElementById('testid').value+"&mode="+selectedValue; },
```

Write getRadioSelectedValue by yourself to get selected radio button value or set some flag on click. Mode param in GET request will indicates the state of the button, so you can return proper response.